# Can't send task to celery from python with apply_async

Tags: python, django, mongodb, shell, celery

I'm using:

```
celery[mongodb]==3.1.23
django-celery==3.1.17
```

Problem is - sometimes (really often) i can't start tasks from django shell or from my other tasks using apply_async, program just hang on this command.

I try run code like:

```
my_task.apply_async(
    args=[object_id],
    queue='my_queue')
```

And its just hangs without any result. I cant figure out why can this happened.

If i need to provide more detailed data, let me know.

i try using strace on process django shell got this log (attaching last lines of it) when calling apply_async:

```
socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 13
connect(13, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(27026), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "4a67:6b8:0:f0e:7543:7rh8:a28:gtbc", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = 0

getsockname(13, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(60033), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "2a45:6b8:0:f0e:8034:7gtd:a28:hy6b", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, [28]) = 0
connect(13, {sa_family=AF_UNSPEC, sa_data="\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"}, 16) = 0
connect(13, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(27026), sin_addr=inet_addr("86.223.186.12")}, 16) = 0
getsockname(13, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(50388), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::ffff:37.9.91.95", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, [28]) = 0
close(13)                               = 0
socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 13
setsockopt(13, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
fcntl(13, F_GETFL)                      = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(13, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)   = 0
setsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, [0], 4) = 0
connect(13, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(27026), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "2a45:6b8:0:f0e:8034:7gtd:a28:hy6b", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
poll([{fd=13, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 4000) = 1 ([{fd=13, revents=POLLOUT}])
getsockopt(13, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
fcntl(13, F_GETFL)                      = 0x802 (flags O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)
fcntl(13, F_SETFL, O_RDWR)              = 0
sendto(13, ":\0\0\0\254\376\245\33\0\0\0\0\324\7\0\0\0\0\0\0admin.$cmd\0\0"..., 58, 0, NULL, 0) = 58
recvfrom(13, "\344\1\0\0\255\351Ct\254\376\245\33\1\0\0\0", 16, 0, NULL, NULL) = 16
recvfrom(13, "\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\300\1\0\0\2setName"..., 468, 0, NULL, NULL) = 468
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)          = 20
read(20, "\3a\240\371\34\342\273", 7)   = 7
close(20)                               = 0
sendto(13, "\230\0\0\0\202\256\213C\0\0\0\0\324\7\0\0\0\0\0\0dogma.$cmd\0\0"..., 152, 0, NULL, 0) = 152
recvfrom(13, "\267\0\0\0\274\351Ct\202\256\213C\1\0\0\0", 16, 0, NULL, NULL) = 16
recvfrom(13, "\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\223\0\0\0\20convers"..., 167, 0, NULL, NULL) = 167
futex(0x11bb8c0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
sendto(13, "\274\0\0\0Ih<\21\0\0\0\0\324\7\0\0\0\0\0\0dogma.$cmd\0\0"..., 188, 0, NULL, 0) = 188
recvfrom(13, "|\0\0\0X\352CtIh<\21\1\0\0\0", 16, 0, NULL, NULL) = 16
recvfrom(13, "\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0X\0\0\0\20convers"..., 108, 0, NULL, NULL) = 108
sendto(13, "`\0\0\0\245\347\226\35\0\0\0\0\324\7\0\0\0\0\0\0dogma.$cmd\0\0"..., 96, 0, NULL, 0) = 96
recvfrom(13, "^\0\0\0]\352Ct\245\347\226\35\1\0\0\0", 16, 0, NULL, NULL) = 16
recvfrom(13, "\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0:\0\0\0\20convers"..., 78, 0, NULL, NULL) = 78
sendto(13, "x\0\0\0\366&\373T\0\0\0\0\324\7\0\0\0\0\0\0dogma.$cmd\0\0"...,       120, 0, NULL, 0) = 120
recvfrom(13,
```

When i do ctrl+c in django shell to kill task sending i receive the following output:

```
/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test/my_tasks.py in 
send_task_to_celery(my_args):
    850     my_task.apply_async(
    851         args=[my_args],
--> 852         queue='my_queue'
    853     )

/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.pyc in apply_async(self, args, kwargs, task_id, producer, link, link_error, **options)
    563             self.name, args, kwargs, task_id=task_id, producer=producer,
    564             link=link, link_error=link_error, result_cls=self.AsyncResult,
--> 565             **dict(self._get_exec_options(), **options)
    566         )
    567 

/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.pyc in send_task(self, name, args, kwargs, countdown, eta, task_id, producer, connection, router, result_cls, expires, publisher, link, link_error, add_to_parent, reply_to, **options)
    352                 task_id=task_id, expires=expires,
    353                 callbacks=maybe_list(link), errbacks=maybe_list(link_error),
--> 354                 reply_to=reply_to or self.oid, **options
    355             )
    356         result = (result_cls or self.AsyncResult)(task_id)

/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.pyc in publish_task(self, task_name, task_args, task_kwargs, countdown, eta, task_id, group_id, taskset_id, expires, exchange, exchange_type, event_dispatcher, retry, retry_policy, queue, now, retries, chord, callbacks, errbacks, routing_key, serializer, delivery_mode, compression, reply_to, time_limit, soft_time_limit, declare, headers, send_before_publish, before_receivers, send_after_publish, after_receivers, send_task_sent, sent_receivers, **kwargs)
    308             correlation_id=task_id,
    309             delivery_mode=delivery_mode, declare=declare,
--> 310             **kwargs
    311         )
    312 

/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.pyc in publish(self, body, routing_key, delivery_mode, mandatory, immediate, priority, content_type, content_encoding, serializer, headers, compression, exchange, retry, retry_policy, declare, expiration, **properties)
    170         return publish(body, priority, content_type,
    171                        content_encoding, headers, properties,
--> 172                        routing_key, mandatory, immediate, exchange, declare)
    173 
    174     def _publish(self, body, priority, content_type, content_encoding,

/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.pyc in _ensured(*args, **kwargs)
    447             for retries in count(0):  # for infinity
    448                 try:
--> 449                     return fun(*args, **kwargs)
    450                 except conn_errors as exc:
    451                     if got_connection and not has_modern_errors:

/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.pyc in _publish(self, body, priority, content_type, content_encoding, headers, properties, routing_key, mandatory, immediate, exchange, declare)
    182         if declare:
    183             maybe_declare = self.maybe_declare
--> 184             [maybe_declare(entity) for entity in declare]
    185         return channel.basic_publish(
    186             message,

/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.pyc in maybe_declare(self, entity, retry, **retry_policy)
    109         during this session."""
    110         if entity:
--> 111             return maybe_declare(entity, self.channel, retry, **retry_policy)
    112 
    113     def publish(self, body, routing_key=None, delivery_mode=None,

/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/common.pyc in maybe_declare(entity, channel, retry, **retry_policy)
    118         return _imaybe_declare(entity, declared, ident,
    119                                channel, **retry_policy)
--> 120     return _maybe_declare(entity, declared, ident, channel)
    121 
    122 

/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/common.pyc in _maybe_declare(entity, declared, ident, channel)
    125     if not channel.connection:
    126         raise RecoverableConnectionError('channel disconnected')
--> 127     entity.declare()
    128     if declared is not None and ident:
    129         declared.add(ident)

/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/entity.pyc in declare(self, nowait)
    520         if self.exchange:
    521             self.exchange.declare(nowait)
--> 522         self.queue_declare(nowait, passive=False)
    523 
    524         if self.exchange and self.exchange.name:

/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/entity.pyc in queue_declare(self, nowait, passive)
    546                                          auto_delete=self.auto_delete,
    547                                          arguments=self.queue_arguments,
--> 548                                          nowait=nowait)
    549         if not self.name:
    550             self.name = ret[0]
/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/__init__.pyc in queue_declare(self, queue, passive, **kwargs)
    445         else:
    446             self._new_queue(queue, **kwargs)
--> 447         return queue_declare_ok_t(queue, self._size(queue), 0)
    448 
    449     def queue_delete(self, queue, if_unused=False, if_empty=False, **kwargs):

/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/mongodb.pyc in _size(self, queue)
    122             return self.get_broadcast_cursor(queue).get_size()
    123 
--> 124         return self.get_messages().find({'queue': queue}).count()
    125 
    126     def _put(self, queue, message, **kwargs):

/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.pyc in count(self, with_limit_and_skip)
    706                 cmd["skip"] = self.__skip
    707 
--> 708         return self.__collection._count(cmd)
    709 
    710     def distinct(self, key):

/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.pyc in _count(self, cmd)
   1197                                 codec_options=self.codec_options._replace(
   1198                                     document_class=dict),
-> 1199                                 read_concern=self.read_concern)
   1200         if res.get("errmsg", "") == "ns missing":
   1201             return 0

/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.pyc in _command(self, sock_info, command, slave_ok, read_preference, codec_options, check, allowable_errors, read_concern)
    203                                  check,
    204                                  allowable_errors,
--> 205                                  read_concern=read_concern)
    206 
    207     def __create(self, options):

/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.pyc in command(self, dbname, spec, slave_ok, read_preference, codec_options, check, allowable_errors, check_keys, read_concern)
    216         # Catch socket.error, KeyboardInterrupt, etc. and close ourselves.
    217         except BaseException as error:
--> 218             self._raise_connection_failure(error)
    219 
    220     def send_message(self, message, max_doc_size):

/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.pyc in _raise_connection_failure(self, error)
    344             _raise_connection_failure(self.address, error)
    345         else:
--> 346             raise error
    347 
    348     def __eq__(self, other):
KeyboardInterrupt:
```

It seams to me that the problem is connected with mongodb, not with celery/python, am i right? How can i diagnose such a problem? For that should i look?
    MongoDB server version: 3.0.11

Comment: Do you think you are passing args wrong ? shouldn't  u use my_task.apply_async(*[object_id], queue='my_queue') not args=[object_id]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my broker - i use mongodb for it and it took a lot of time to write a task in it. Don't use databases as brokers unless you have to.